# Is there any method that can tell me what type of differential equation I'm dealing with?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

When I face a ODE, sometimes I don't know if it's a separable ODE, an exact ODE, a Bernoulli ODE, etc. Is there any method to verify this?

Comment: Good pattern recognition usually requires lots of practice. However, Wolfram Alpha can often tell you the type of ODE.

Comment: There are several methods: learning the pattern and the methods to deal with them (not an option for lazy students), lots of exercise (not an option for lazy students), and asking at MSE. The latter guarantees they'll *never* recognize the pattern without help.

Answer (score 0):

It is not always easy.  Here are some first steps.

If the problem is written in the form.

$f(x,y)\ dx + g(x,y)\ dy = 0$

You probably have an exact diff eq, and you should check that $\frac {\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac {\partial f}{\partial x}.$

If it fails the test then then rewrite it like so.

$\frac {dy}{dx} = -\frac {f(x,y)}{g(x,y)}$

If you have a diff eq in the form $\frac {dy}{dx} = f(x,y)$

Can you write manipulate it such that it is a function of $\frac {y}{x}$ ?  If you can then it is a Bernoulli diff eq.

If you can rewrite it as the product of an function of $x$ and a function of $y$ then it is a separable diff eq.

You really do need to investigate the possibilities, before proceeding and deciding which tool to use.